# Assigning authentication token in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a large app running on Devise, Rails 5.

I am trying to create simple token access to the application so the end user could hit localhost:3000/projects.json with a single Curl request by simply providing a token for authentication without an email or password.

The resources I've checked seem to create a session through an email and password, then create a token, then another request:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

http://www.jianshu.com/p/8068d539a539

How could I accomplish access with a single API token?

**Note I am using devise for this, because I am using the :lockable module to protect against brute force attacks on the API

Comment: Can you develp on the way the user gets the token first place ? You can create a migration and add a token column to your model : https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/23/has-secure-token-to-generate-unique-random-token-in-rails-5.html then customize a route in order to accept 2 params: id and token.. authing through Devise seems much more secure though

Comment: I personnaly use this Rails token functionnality for handling questions to the company team. I want it not to be fully public, yet dont need super thorough security. (and complete strangers with no account created can ask questions, just with their email)

Comment: The devise token is a temp session token that can be received with devise_token_auth. Then used to authenticate in a separate request. Yeah, I would hate to run with 2 auth systems, but sounds like that is the best way to auth w a token only